# Neural network with variable length of input and variable length output

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I am tasked with the creation of a classifier model which predicts the probability with which an item will be returned in an e-commerce setting. This classifier model is supposed to take all other items within the same order into account as well, as there might be relations between these items.

Let's call the number of items within an order, which we will call n.
Since n is variable and can in theory range from 1 to infinity the model should be able to take a variable number of items as input. Each item has a select number of features that are unique to it, such as the price of the item, the quantity which the customer has ordered, the weight of the article, the return rate over the past 30 days, the number of items the customer has bought this item etc. Let's call the vector which represents an individual item i.

There are also features which are identical for all items within the same order, such as the payment type, currency, shipment method etc. lets call this vector o.

Ideally I want the model to take a variable number of i's and the o as input and produce an output which is the same length as the number of items n which we gave as input to the model. Each value should be the probability with which the individual item will be returned.

Is it even possible to have a flexible length input and output? If not, should I limit the output of the network to a single value and give in the items in a different order such that the item I am trying to predict a probability for is passed in last?

I am really lost here and appreciate your help.

This is the format my data is in now:

```
order_features = ['order_id', 'vendor_country', 'currency',
                  'ordered_quantity', 'price', 'total_price', 'is_returned',
                  'number_of_items', 'past_rr_customer', 
                  'past_rr_shipment_carrier', 'past_rr_payment_type',
                  'past_rr_shipment_method', 'vendor_rr_30_days',
                  'avg_order_price', 'total_order_price', 'repeat_customer',
                  'weekday', 'month', 'month_progression']

item_features = ['order_id', 'position_number', 'article_type', 'article_weight', 
       'ordered_quantity', 'price', 'total_price', 
       'past_rr_article', 'past_rr_ca', 'past_rr_shipment_carrier', 
       'past_rr_payment_type', 'past_rr_shipment_method', 
       'vendor_rr_30_days', 'times_bought', 'is_returned']

one_hot_cols = ['article_type', 'currency', 'vendor_country', 'month', 'weekday']

norm_cols = ['position_number', 'article_weight', 
           'ordered_quantity', 'price', 'total_price',
           'number_of_items', 'past_rr_article', 'past_rr_customer', 'past_rr_ca',
           'past_rr_shipment_carrier', 'past_rr_payment_type',
           'past_rr_shipment_method', 'article_rr_30_days', 'vendor_rr_30_days',
           'avg_order_price', 'total_order_price', 'repeat_customer',
           'times_bought', 'month_progression']

drop_cols = ['article_id', 'vendor_id','vendor_zip', 'customer_id', 'customer_zip', 
             'customer_country', 'business_type', 'shipment_method', 
             'shipment_carrier_name', 'payment_method', 'article_name']

df = pd.read_pickle('../data/enhanced_data.pkl')
df['weekday'] = df.order_date.dt.weekday
df['month'] = df.order_date.dt.month 
df['month_progression'] = df.order_date.dt.day / df.order_date.dt.daysinmonth
df['article_weight'] = df['article_weight'].fillna(0)

# Splits based on date
X_train, X_test = chronological_split(df, 0.9)
# One hot encodes the categorical features and scales the numerical features
X_train, X_test = pipeline(X_train, X_test, one_hot_cols, norm_cols, drop_cols)

order_values_train = X_train.drop_duplicates('order_id', keep='first')[order_features]
order_values_train = order_values_train.set_index('order_id')
order_values_test = X_test.drop_duplicates('order_id', keep='first')[order_features]
order_values_test = order_values_test.set_index('order_id')

item_values_train = X_train[item_features].groupby('order_id').agg(lambda x: list(x))
item_values_train = item_values_train[item_values_train['price'].apply(len) != 0]
item_values_test = X_test[item_features].groupby('order_id').agg(lambda x: list(x))
item_values_test = item_values_test[item_values_test['price'].apply(len) != 0]


X_train = pd.concat([order_values_train, item_values_train], axis=1)
X_test = pd.concat([order_values_test, item_values_test], axis=1)
y_train = X_train.pop('is_returned')
y_test = X_test.pop('is_returned')
```